# Blank space on the right of page

Tags: space, blank-line

I designed a website in the past and i decided to design it again for present. Now i want to make it responsive but there is a black blank space on the right. But i don't know what is the problem i am searching for it but i can't see. What you guys thinking about it? Example page: http://www.locusludus.com/listeler/
In some pages i haven't finished yet so this page will be a good example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m27r5.jpg)

Comment: Use the browser dev tools -- press F12 in either Chrome, Firefox or IE to bring them up. Then use the element inspection tool to examine the various bits of your page. Look for unexpected padding and margin, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion. I've finally found the problem:

```
.text {
  padding: 16px 12px;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 976px;
}
```

In this css code i've changed padding to: 16px 0px. Blank space was 24px and it was because of this padding.